# x264_encoder_encode() как посмотреть тело функции?

Tags: c++, vlc

В процессе работы с исходным кодом плеера VLC ([Ссылка на GitHub](https://github.com/sunqueen/vlc-2.2.1.32-2013)) появилась необходимость изучить работу функции кодирования `x264_encoder_encode()` для кодека `h.264`, однако тело функции найти мне не удалось. Подскажите, где его можно увидеть?

Comment: Очевидно, что в `libx264`, исходники скорее всего закрыты для общего доступа.

Comment: [ссылка](http://www.videolan.org/developers/x264.html) говорит об обратном

Comment: А нет, что-то я таки нашёл - http://git.videolan.org/git/x264.git